# How to use pipeline communication between parent process and child process using loop?

Tags: c, unix

```
        else if(child_pid == 0) //child process
        {
                char success[] = "success";
                close(c2k_fd[1]);
                close(k2c_fd[0]);
                char read_buf[BUFSIZ];
                read(c2k_fd[0], read_buf, BUFSIZ);
                printf("[child] %s\n", read_buf);
                write(k2c_fd[1], success, sizeof(success));
        }
        else //parent process
        {
                close(c2k_fd[0]);
                close(k2c_fd[1]);

                char success[] = "success";
                char read_buf[BUFSIZ];

                for(i=0; i<4; i++)
                {
                      printf("[parnt] loop start\n");
                      write(c2k_fd[1], success, sizeof(success));
                      wait();

                      read(k2c_fd[0], read_buf, BUFSIZ);
                      printf("[parnt] %s\n", read_buf);
                }
        }
```

There is a problem using pipe communication. I want to send and receive strings between parents and children process through for loop, but if I write like this, it will only work once. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to accomplish. The child process looks like it will read once, then write once, then it's done: the child portion is not looping, but the parent appears to expect this.  Also, `wait()` is expecting to be called with the address of an integer where status can be places, so this can't be right.

When it "works once", what does the output look like?

Comment: This code cannot work like you want: the child runs **one time** through the statements in the `if` block: it will read once from the parent, write once to the parent, then exit.  Did you intend a loop inside the child?

Also: when the child exits, if the parent attempts to write to the pipe, it will be killed with `SIGPIPE` (attempt to write to a pipe where the other end is gone), so be prepared for that as well.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I saw your comments and solved some of the problems. I thought that if I use loop in the parent process, my child process will work and send and receive messages repeatedly. I knew I had to loop the fork function to work that way. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I thought this would work in the process of changing a program from signal to pipe. But no. Thank you for your comments.